# Wordpress: 406 error code when inserting images

Tags: wordpress

When trying to insert an image into my Wordpress post (hosted on HostPapa), I'm receiving a 406 error code. I've opened up the Chrome console I get the following error codes:

'Failed to load resource: (resource link - wordpress image/gif)
server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'

'Failed to load resource: (resource link - the post we're trying to make)
server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)'

I've tried changing the image that's in the post and I get the same error message. I can also make a post without an image. I'm not sure if the first error is responsible for the second - the first error isn't the image I'm trying to add to the post.

Any help is greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

For anyone else having this issue:
The error was to do with HostPapa's 'mod security'. If you go to 'Mod Security' from the CPanel you can disable it.